# Find two closest points on two functions

Tags: linear-algebra

We have two functions:

$$\begin{align*}
y &= x^4-5x^3+2x^2-5 \\
y &= -11x-20
\end{align*}$$

My task is to find two closest points that can be found on these two functions.

Can somebody give any hints on how to solve these type of exercises?

Thank you!

Comment: Do you mean the closest points of the curves, or the minimum difference between the two functions?

Comment: The minimum difference between the two functions. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to minimize $x^4-5 x^3+2 x^2+11 x+15$.  Take the derivative, set that to $0$, and solve.  Unfortunately this is an irreducible cubic, so the solutions are not very 
nice.  There are three real roots: approximately $-.6828742578$, $1.275428188$, $3.157446070$.  I'll leave it to you to find which of these gives the minimum.